# SQL Firebird Pivot table conversion required

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a procedure that generated Friday and Thursday date in firebird. I use the following query to generate a list of data:

```
    select w_start as "Friday", w_end as "Thursday",
(select count(*) from course C 
                         inner join enrolment E on E.cod_course=C.id
                         where E.date_enrolled between w_start and w_end
                                   and C_TYPE = 'PU' and CONFIRMED='C'  
                                  and (C.name like :PublicCourseOption1  or C.name like :PublicCourseOption2 or C.name like :PublicCourseOption3  or C.name like :PublicCourseOption4 
                                         or C.VERSION like :CourseVersion1 or C.version like :CourseVersion2  or C.version like :CourseVersion3 )
) as "Enrolments",
(select list(distinct promotype, ', ') from programmers where datesent between w_start and w_end) as "Promos", 
(select list(distinct course, ', ') from programmers where datesent between w_start and w_end) as "Courses"
from get_weeks(:dtFromDate, :dtToDate) wks
order by w_start
```

It generates the following result:

```
Friday      Thursday    Enrolments  Promos                Courses
04/01/2013  10/01/2013  5           FAX                   WHS
11/01/2013  17/01/2013  11          EMAIL                 WHS
18/01/2013  24/01/2013  6           FAX                   WHS
25/01/2013  31/01/2013  12          EMAIL, FAX            RTW, YSM103
01/02/2013  07/02/2013  17          EMAIL, FAX, Wcover    REF-CIT, WHS Toll, WorkCover
08/02/2013  14/02/2013  19          FAX                   HSR HUR- INFO
15/02/2013  21/02/2013  12          FAX                   MC
22/02/2013  28/02/2013  19          EMAIL, FAX            ARTW, DYS25, MC
01/03/2013  07/03/2013  22          COMCARE, FAX, Wcover  COMCARE, COMM, WorkCover
08/03/2013  14/03/2013  13          FAX                   HSR
15/03/2013  21/03/2013  12
22/03/2013  28/03/2013  16          FAX                   HSR
```

Does anyone know how to convert the data into a pivot table showing as follows:

```
Promos- Course - 10/01/2013 (Thursday Date)    - 17/01/2013 (Thursday Date)
FAX   -  WHS   - 15 enrolments                 - 25 enrolments
EMAIL -  MC    - 14 Enrolments                 - 36 enrolments
```

The dates are dynamically created and can vary every time the query is run, so static query wont work for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

In my line of work we ran into a similar situation. Our code was being executed from a client, so we ended up doing was creating a stored procedure that returned the SQL statement, then we executed the SQL statement returned.

In order to the accomplish your task, I created a helper stored procedure called `X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE`:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE (
    PROMOS VARCHAR(100),
    COURSES VARCHAR(100),
    DATE_STRING VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS (
    ENROLLMENTS INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN

  SELECT SUM(ENROLLMENTS)
  FROM TABLE_X
  WHERE TABLE_X.PROMOS = :PROMOS
        AND TABLE_X.COURSES = :COURSES
        AND TABLE_X.THURSDAY = :DATE_STRING
  INTO ENROLLMENTS;

  SUSPEND;
END
```

And I created the following using EXECUTE BLOCK, but could easily be placed in another stored procedure.

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
RETURNS (
    SQL VARCHAR(3000))
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE SELECT_SQL VARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE VARIABLE WHERE_SQL VARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE VARIABLE PROMOS VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE VARIABLE COURSES VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE VARIABLE THURSDAY VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE VARIABLE ENROLLMENTS INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE FIELD_ID INTEGER; --DECLARE VARIABLE S varchar(1000)
DECLARE VARIABLE FIELD_COUNT INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT_SQL = 'SELECT distinct promos, courses ,' || ASCII_CHAR(13);
  WHERE_SQL = 'FROM table_x' || ASCII_CHAR(13);

  FIELD_ID = 0;

  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT THURSDAY)
  FROM TABLE_X
  INTO :FIELD_COUNT;

  FOR
  SELECT DISTINCT THURSDAY
  FROM TABLE_X
  INTO :THURSDAY
  DO
  BEGIN
    FIELD_ID = :FIELD_ID + 1;
    IF (:FIELD_ID = :FIELD_COUNT) THEN
      SELECT_SQL = :SELECT_SQL || 'T' || :FIELD_ID || '.Enrollments ' || 'Thu_' || REPLACE(:THURSDAY, '/', '_') || ASCII_CHAR(13);
    ELSE
      SELECT_SQL = :SELECT_SQL || 'T' || :FIELD_ID || '.Enrollments ' || 'Thu_' || REPLACE(:THURSDAY, '/', '_') || ',' || ASCII_CHAR(13);

    WHERE_SQL = :WHERE_SQL || 'LEFT OUTER JOIN X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE ( table_x.PROMOS,table_x.COURSES, ''' || :THURSDAY || ''') T' || :FIELD_ID || ' on (1 = 1)' || ASCII_CHAR(13);
    --    WHERE_SQL = :WHERE_SQL || 'INNER JOIN ( Select Sum(Enrollments) Enrollments from table_x where promos = ''' || :PROMOS || ''' and Courses = ''' || :COURSES || ''' and thursday = ''' || :THURSDAY || ''') T' || :FIELD_ID || ' on (1 = 1)' || ASCII_CHAR(13);

  END
  SQL = :SELECT_SQL || :WHERE_SQL;
  SUSPEND;
END;
```

When you execute the stored procedure it will return back the following SQL, which you can then execute.

```
SELECT distinct promos, courses ,
T1.Enrollments Thu_07_02_2013,
T2.Enrollments Thu_07_03_2013,
T3.Enrollments Thu_10_01_2013,
T4.Enrollments Thu_14_02_2013,
T5.Enrollments Thu_14_03_2013,
T6.Enrollments Thu_17_01_2013,
T7.Enrollments Thu_21_02_2013,
T8.Enrollments Thu_21_03_2013,
T9.Enrollments Thu_24_01_2013,
T10.Enrollments Thu_28_02_2013,
T11.Enrollments Thu_28_03_2013,
T12.Enrollments Thu_31_01_2013
FROM table_x
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE ( table_x.PROMOS,table_x.COURSES, '07/02/2013') T1 on (1 = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE ( table_x.PROMOS,table_x.COURSES, '07/03/2013') T2 on (1 = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE ( table_x.PROMOS,table_x.COURSES, '10/01/2013') T3 on (1 = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE ( table_x.PROMOS,table_x.COURSES, '14/02/2013') T4 on (1 = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE ( table_x.PROMOS,table_x.COURSES, '14/03/2013') T5 on (1 = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE ( table_x.PROMOS,table_x.COURSES, '17/01/2013') T6 on (1 = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE ( table_x.PROMOS,table_x.COURSES, '21/02/2013') T7 on (1 = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE ( table_x.PROMOS,table_x.COURSES, '21/03/2013') T8 on (1 = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE ( table_x.PROMOS,table_x.COURSES, '24/01/2013') T9 on (1 = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE ( table_x.PROMOS,table_x.COURSES, '28/02/2013') T10 on (1 = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE ( table_x.PROMOS,table_x.COURSES, '28/03/2013') T11 on (1 = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_GET_ENROLLMENTS_FOR_DATE ( table_x.PROMOS,table_x.COURSES, '31/01/2013') T12 on (1 = 1)
```

A few things I want to point out is that I couldn't get the column headers to come exactly as you wanted.
This example only works on Thursday field, you will need to make changes to code to handle the Friday field.
I am assuming that you might have multiples of same date, promo and courses so I am summing the enrollments fields in the helper stored procedure.